# Spring security - Custom filter and entry point for rest service

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need to develop the security of a rest service wirh Spring Security (version 4.0.3. RELEASE).

The scenario is:

1. authenticate the client performing the request (client id + client
   token on custom header)
2. in case of errors, a JSON response needs to be sent

I created a custom  `OncePerRequestFilter` that does the job of reading a custom token just as if it was a `basic auth` token.

```
public class MyClientAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // omitting implementation
    }

}
```

Then I created my own `AuthenticationEntryPoint` that does the job of writing the JSON error in the response.

```
public class MyAuthorizationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // omitting implementation
    }

}
```

Then I wired them up like that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements TogatherWebApiCostants {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebApiSecurityConfig.class);

    private @Inject Environment environment;

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationEntryPoint clientAuthorizationEntryPoint() {
        return new MyAuthorizationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Filter clientAuthorizationFilter() {
        return new MyAuthorizationFilter();
    }

    /**
     * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity)
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Configuring HTTP security");

        // @formatter:on
        http
            .addFilterBefore(clientAuthorizationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(clientAuthorizationEntryPoint());
        // @formatter:off
    }
```

}

Everything works, except the custom entry point. It doesn't get fired and it seems Spring is still using the default one. I've also tried to switch to XML config (I'm much more used to it rather than with JavaConfig approach) but the behavior remains the same.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

NOTE: I tried to debug Spring Security by adding a logger `org.springframework.security` with level set to `debug`, but I dont see any log message

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**EDIT: Adding current workaround**

As of now, lacking an elegant solution, I just explicitly called the entry point from the filter.

```
public class MyClientAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    ...
    private @Inject AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            // omitting logic
        } catch(AuthenticationException ae) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            entryPoint.commence(request, response, ae);
            return;         
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you throw an exepction in your `MyClientAuthorizationFilter`, if the user is not authenticated?

Comment: @dur yes. I throw custom exceptions. They all extends `org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I experience the exact same thing...

Comment: @Hoof I didn't find an actual solution as of now. What I did is a workaround... Not elegant, but still working ;-) I added it to the original post

Answer (score 1):

You should paste your filter after ExceptionTranslationFilter

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    log.debug("Configuring HTTP security");

    // @formatter:on
    http
        .addFilterAfter(clientAuthorizationFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(clientAuthorizationEntryPoint());
    // @formatter:off
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are passing wrong object in `authenticationEntryPoint()` of `WebApiSecurityConfig` implementation class, pass `AuthenticationEntryPoint` implementation class object which is here `TogatherWebApiClientAuthorizationEntryPoint` and check if you are getting custom error.

Comment: it's a typo, my bad. `MyAuthorizationEntryPoint` is actually the same as `TogatherWebApiClientAuthorizationEntryPoint`, I forgot to anonymize it.